# How can I edit the color scheme for NON-EDITOR panes in IntelliJ IDEA?

Tags: intellij-idea

I've spent some time googling and asking in IRC, and for some reason, I am the only person who seems to actually care about this issue, as no leads are forthcoming.  And I'm sure this will sound minor to most people.  That said...

I really really like the Solarized theme for editing.  Ergo, I use it for my main code panes in IDEA.  However, because IDEA separates between "Appearance" settings and "Editor" settings, there is a stark visual contrast between the colors of my editing panes and the other panes in my workspace( project, maven, output, etc ).  The only options available for Themes are either Default or Darcula, and there is no clear way of editing either of them, or adding new ones.  The documentation is entirely unclear on this.

What I'm asking is if there is *any* known way of utilizing the solarized editor theme to also "theme" the rest of IDEA so that I can have a uniform visual feel across the entire IDE.  Or, alternatively, if there is a configuration file that IDEA reads to set up the color and font values?

Thanks.

Comment: Why closing this question ?
__What topics can I ask about here? software tools commonly used by programmers__

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The chrome theme is actually a Java Look&Feel, there is no way to edit its colors without touching the source code.

It's technically possible to install any third-party L&F into JVM and use it in IntelliJ IDEA, but it will most likely look ugly and break the UI in many places. If you decide to go this route, start with the Substance.

It took a lot of resources to make the Darcula theme, implementing your own one with custom colors would be a tough task.